# How to fix RichnessGrid Error in split.default

Tags: r

I tried to use RichnessGrid to count species occurrence on the map. But I am constantly getting the error message

> "Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : 
>     group length is 0 but data length > 0".

By checking other posts, it seems that this is the error message for typos, which is not my case. Does anyone know how to trouble shot this problem?

My data look like this

[image]

I tried a few things: 1. change the resolution option or the type definition; 2. change header of my data; 3. look at the summary of my data and sample data. But nothing worked, and I still could not figure out where went wrong.

```
dput(head(clean))
#subset my df (clean) for RichnessGrid 
dat<-clean %>% select(the.plant.list,longitude,latitude)

# tried to change header but still failed
dat <- dat %>% rename(species = the.plant.list)
head(dat)

RichnessGrid(dat, reso=60, type = "spnum")

#try sample data and code
data(lemurs)
e <- c(-125, -105, 30, 50)
RichnessGrid(lemurs, e, reso = 60, type = "spnum")

#compare sample data and my own
data(lemurs)
data(dat)
summary(lemurs)
summary(dat)
```

Comment: Can you update your post by adding data using `dput(clean)` or if it is too big `dput(head(clean))` ?

Comment: Thank you, I added the code there now.

Comment: No, you need to add the output of `dput(head(clean))` so that we know what kind of data you have and will make this reproducible. Also read how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)